# Oracle insert into select print duplicated row

Tags: oracle, plsql, plsqldeveloper

In a PL/SQL procedure I am executing a INSERT INTO SELECT statement in a table with primary key but I am getting .ORA-00001: unique constraint violated. Is there a way to print the row that is generating the error?

Somenthing like this:

```
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE (A,B,C)
VALUES (1,2,3);

EXCEPTION 
  WHEN DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX  
    THEN DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(MYROW);
```

Comment: You may use dbms error logging to capture the failed row insert

Comment: Or even [DML error logging](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25494/tables.htm#ADMIN10261) ;)